# Different QueryParams, Ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am trying to have 2 GET methods with the same path, but different query params. These are my 2 endpoints:

```
@GET
@Path("list/someObjects")
List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectsByFirstId(@QueryParam("firstId") Integer firstId);

@GET
@Path("list/someObjects")
List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectsBySecondId(@QueryParam("secondId") Integer secondId);
```

However, I get a validation error:

> These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types
> and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.

Shouldn't these two methods be different from each other since they have different query params ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function definition it's the same. Same name, same nr of arguments and same return value. Java compiles as the same. I would advice you to do this:

```java
@GET
@Path("list/someObjects")
List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectsById(@QueryParam("Id") Integer firstId, @QueryParameter("secondId") @DefaultValue("false") boolean isSecondId);
```

This way you can always ask for a the first the list of Object by id like so:
`localhost:8080/list/someObjects?Id=111` and will always use the firstId. If you want to get by the secondId, you can make `localhost:8080/list/someObjects?Id=111&secondId=true`.

Looks like a alternative to your approach. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

A query param doesn't make endpoint different. Query param can be whatever.

```
/list/someObjects?firstId=a&secondId=b
```

this is a valid path for both of those methods, so which one should it call?
In order to have such type you could do:

```
@GET
@Path("list/someObjects")
List<SomeObject> getSomeObjectsBySecondId(@QueryParam(required = false) Integer firstId, @QueryParam(required = false) Integer secondId);
```

And inside logic check which one is filled to continue with code execution.